# get removed and original array using splice and for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, array-splice

I'm trying to create multiple arrays from one array and then add html strings. I use `.splice()` and `for`. My main problem is that `.splice()` only shows the removed arrays and not the first.

Here's what I have so far:

```
array = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2" ,"c3","d1","d2","d3"]

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
array.splice(0,3);
console.log(array[0] + '<br/>' + '<a href="' + array[2] + '">' + array[1] + '</a>');

 }
```

The only problem is that this results in:

```
b1<br/><a href="b3">b2</a>
c1<br/><a href="c3">c2</a>
d1<br/><a href="d3">d2</a>
```

I'm missing the first array which contains the 'a' values. What is the best way to output all these arrays?

Comment: I think something's missing; I see an array called "a", but it's never referenced, and items called "array" which I don't see declared anywhere.

Comment: @lmortenson I presume that is just a typo when writing the code on SO.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995, You're both right. I change the name of the array to 'array'

Answer (score 2):

Just do something like this?

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i+=3){
   console.log(array[i] + '<br/>' + '<a href="' + array[i+2] + '">' + array[i+1] + '</a>');
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ceeL/)

Or you could just move the splice line to the end of the loop.